# Vue.js bind reactive style object px params

Tags: vue.js, styles, bind

I'm try do reactive change style HTML element from range input, but there is a problem style params font-size, height, width and more with **px**

```
<span v-bind:style="myobj.css">Hi all</span>

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app', 
    data: {
        myobj: {
            css: {
                color: '#999999',
                fontSize: '18',
            }
        }
    }
})
<input v-model="myobj.css.fontSize" type="range" min="10" max="32" step="1">
```

but needly - "font-size: 18**px**, how i can do it? I'm try use filter, but is doesnt work with obj

Comment: Class bindings should do the trick for you: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: You undestend my question. I'm how bind class and style, but i don't how bind css integer params with reactive change: if you set params from data fontSize: '12px' it's work from style and don't work in input range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a computed property for your v-model:

```
computed: {
  fontSize: {
    get() {
      const fontPx = /(<?value>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)px/

      if (!fontPx.test(newValue))
        return 0
      
      const { groups: { value } } = newValue.match(fontPx)
      return value
    },
    set(newValue) {
      this.myobj.css.fontsize = newValue + 'px'
    }
  }
}
```

and in your template:

```
<input v-model="fontSize" type="range" min="10" max="32" step="1">
```

EDIT - I just re-read your question. I had the `get` and `set` flipped around. The edited answer should do what you need.

Alternatively, you could use a computed property for the style instead:

```
computed: {
  style() {
    const style = { ...this.myobj.css }
    style.fontsize = style.fontsize + 'px'
    
    return style
  }
}
```

```
<span v-bind:style="style">Hi all</span>
```